# Why starts a exe in bat leads command-line ends with space char?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Bat:

```
START notepad.exe
```

Using WMI winapi to query command line:

```
HRESULT hr = 0;
hr = wbemLocator_.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WbemLocator);
hr = wbemLocator_->ConnectServer(CComBSTR(L"ROOT\\CIMV2"), NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, &wbemServices_);
hr = ::CoSetProxyBlanket(wbemServices_, RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT, RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE, NULL, RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL, RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, NULL, EOAC_NONE);

CComPtr<IEnumWbemClassObject> enumWbemClassObject;
hr = wbemServices_->ExecQuery(CComBSTR(L"WQL"), CComBSTR(WStringUtils::Format(L"SELECT ProcessId, CommandLine, ExecutablePath FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessId = %d", processId).c_str()), WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY, NULL, &enumWbemClassObject);
CComPtr<IWbemClassObject> wbemClassObject;
ULONG count = 0;
hr = enumWbemClassObject->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, &wbemClassObject, &count);

CComVariant commandLineVar;
wbemClassObject->Get(L"CommandLine", 0, &commandLineVar, 0, 0);
```

The `commandLineVar` will end with a blank char.

Here's the screenshot from procexp.exe:
[image]

How does this happen? How to avoid this?

Comment: What are you expecting

Comment: @cup The command line without a tailing blank char from wmi or procexp.exe because when I started it in bat I didn't provide a blank char.

Comment: What happens if you add a filename after notepad.exe - is there an extra space after the filename?

Comment: @cup No, but there are 2 blank chars between exe and the filename.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this behavior but I don't know why it happens. Any application that uses "standard" command line argument parsing will probably not notice.

Silly workarounds:

```
call notepad.exe&REM if you don't mind the batch waiting

start /B cmd.exe /C call notepad.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Just using WMIC.exe, the CommandLine is returned correctly, *(I have enclosed the result in brackets to show that there is no trailing space character)*:

Batch file:

```sh
Start %SystemRoot%\System32\notepad.exe
For /F Tokens^=6^ Delims^=^" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe Process Where "CommandLine Like '%%notepad.exe%%' And Not CommandLine Like '%%[%%]notepad.exe[%%]%%'" Get CommandLine /Format:MOF 2^>NUL') Do @Echo [%%G]
```

Output:

```sh
C:\Users\user1633272>Start C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe

C:\Users\user1633272>For /F Tokens^=6^ Delims^=^" %G In ('C:\Windows\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe Process Where "CommandLine Like '%notepad.exe%' And Not CommandLine Like '%[%]notepad.exe[%]%'" Get CommandLine /Format:MOF 2^>NUL') Do @Echo [%G]
[C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe]
```

Even if you include additional trailing spaces in the `start` command line, those are stripped by the parser and not passed as part of the command line string so those are not returned as part of the CommandLine property either.

Note you should be aware that my WMIC command additionally filters with a NOT LIKE string, otherwise the WMIC command itself would be returned, because that additionally includes the string `notepad.exe` within its content.

I assume therefore in your particular case, that the pType is not defined as a string, when retrieved from the COM object, whereas my MOF formatting above suggests that COM to MOF is requesting/translating it correctly.

Comment: It only happens when starting from bat, my C++ code does not get blank char for app started by clicking. You can have a try with procexp.exe.

Comment: You never mentioned that at all in your question @user1633272. You simply showed the content of a bat file, and asked in your title about it starting an exe from a bat file. Of course now the question arises, why would you start an exe from C++, by asking cmd.exe to run a batch file with a command to start the target exe when you could just start it directly from C++. I think your question requires much clarification, along with a real world problem from a real world command, because this now seems more like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).